# Microsoft Learning Gateway - MLG Deployment on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have installed MOSS 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2, and also MLG installed on Sharepoint server 2010. but when i try to create **School Portal Site** it generates error.

I want to know **is MLG - Microsoft Learning Gateway support / configure on Sharepoint 2010** ?.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly Saifal - you were not able to create a site based on a template from the Microsoft Learning Gateway kit?

AFAIK is the Learning Gateway not yet available for Sharepoint 2010, so I don't know how you were even able to install it.
 The [Learning Gateway codeplex site](http://lg.codeplex.com/) is only for Sharepoint 2007, the [Microsoft UK site only lists availability for Sharepoint 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/education/schools/products/learning-gateway/sharepoint-server-2007.aspx).

Comment: if the answer is sufficient you may mark it as the answer with the checkmark on the left to the answer